# Access children using parent name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am programming a simple game and I need to reuse the same line in `Grid` many times. I have a block of 5 `Rectangle`s named 1 to 5. What I want to do is have x of these blocks numbered and then access the `Rectangle`s as `block1.rectangle1.someMethod()`.
An easy approach would be just have `rectangle1` and `rectangle26` and so on but that is annoying...

### The block is this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="point1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Rectangle Name="point2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Name="point3" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Name="point4" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Rectangle Name="point5" Grid.Column="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that in xaml. Try to create them in codebehind...

Answer (score 1):

Name the Grid (parent) and use its `Children` Property to iterate through all child elements:

```
foreach(UIElement element in grid1.Children)
{
    Rectangle rect = element as Rectangle;
    if(rect == null) continue;

    rect.someMethod();
}
```

Same thing can be done with your "blocks" off course

```
foreach(UIElement outerElement in gridParent.Children)
{
    Grid grid = outerElement as Grid;
    if(grid == null) continue;

    foreach(UIElement element in grid.Children)
    {
        Rectangle rect = element as Rectangle;
        if(rect == null) continue;

        rect.someMethod();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create all of those "blocks" by hand, I'd recommend using an [ItemsControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) with a [DataTemplate](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html) to generate those for you based on a [ViewModel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level).